Does this group von Neumann algebra satisfy a universal property?
If $G$ is a group and $K$ is a commutative ring, the unital $K$-algebra $K[G]$ and the canonical group homomorphism $\delta:g\mapsto\delta_g$ from $G$ to $K[G]^\times$ are certainly interesting to consider for an algebraist because of the universal property they satisfy: if $A$ is another unital $K$-algebra and $\varphi$ is a group homomorphism from $G$ to $A^\times$, then there is a unique algebra homomorphism $\psi$ from $K[G]$ to $A$ such that $\varphi=\psi\circ\delta$.
Now let $G$ be a locally compact Hausdorff topological group and denote by $\lambda$ the left regular representation of $G$ in $L^2(G)$. For an analyst, the von Neumann algebra $\lambda(G)''$ on $L^2(G)$ generated by $\lambda(G)$ and the group homomorphism $g\mapsto\lambda(g)$ from $G$ to $(\lambda(G)'')^\times$ are certainly interesting to consider because of their relation with Fourier analysis: one can introduce a "quantum group" $\widehat G$ which plays the role of Pontryagin dual of $G$, $\lambda(G)''$ and its predual play the roles of $L^\infty(\widehat G)$ and $L^1(\widehat G)$ respectively and $\lambda$ plays the role of the Fourier transform.
I do not know however why an algebraist would ever find $\lambda(G)''$ and $\lambda$ interesting, hence my question:
Does there exist a good class of von Neumann algebras, a good class of group homomorphisms from $G$ to groups of invertible elements of von Neumann algebras of that class as well as a good class of algebra homomorphisms between von Neumann algebras of that class with respect to which $\lambda(G)''$ and $\lambda$ satisfy a universal property similar to that of the group algebra?
Remarks. 1) I guess the answer is probably yes when $G$ is discrete and amenable. 2) A similar question question could be asked more generally about the crossed product of a von Neumann dynamical system, since the purely algebraic counterpart, I believe, does satisfy a nice universal property.

Even for amenable discrete $G$, you need something like the codomain is a tracial von Neumann algebra and the homomorphism maps into the unitary group and induces the left-regular trace. For discrete icc group $G$, $\lambda(G)’’$ is simple as just an algebra, which indicates you’re unlikely to get anything of the sort you’re looking for.

(I should point out the first sentence of my comment applies to discrete groups in general. I’m only saying amenable to indicate requiring amenability isn’t really helpful.)

The body of your post asks more general, and more provocative, questions than the title. So which is your focus? For instance, "I do not know why an algebraist would ever find $\lambda(G)''$ and $\lambda$ interesting" is a strange sentence to read, unless "complex representation theory of finite groups" is not interesting to algebraists

Not everything has to satisfy a universal property, and I say this as someone who is more sympathetic to category theory than most functional analysts I have encountered.

In any case, if you want the universal vN algebra for cts unitary reps of locally compact groups, take the bidual of the full group Cstar algebra - I believe that this was studied in some old papers of J. Ernest.
